# Adding onfocus to codeigniter array in form

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-2

I'd like to add an onfocus command to an array in Codeigniter. I generally add this code to my inputs:

```
onfocus="this.value=''"
```

This I'm using an array (see below) and need to know how to add onfocus to it (and if it can't be done in an array, where can it be done?

```
$login = array(
    'name'  => 'login',
    'id'    => 'login',
    'value' => set_value('login', 'Email'),
);
```

and for the input:

```
<?php echo form_input($login); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this once the page is loaded to have a better control on it. Try this.

```
$(function(){
   //if you have a id to input element then you can use
   //id selector which is much better than attribute selector.
   $('input[name=login]').focus(function(){
       //Write your code here to do on focus
       //this.value = '';
   })
});
```

Comment: This is a better way of doing it.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards What makes you say that this answer is better than yours?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Trying this now

Comment: @ShankarSangoli There's a problem with this function for me; I removed the accepted answer because it adds the onfocus as soon as the page loads. This means that the user can't see the form field label and won't know what to enter in the field. The user needs to be able to see the field with its value and then when the user selects the input box, then I want the field to clear.

Comment: @chowwy - It was because I was triggering the focus event on page load , check my edited answer now.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Thanks. Accepted the answer--final this time.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli It’s best practice to have JavaScript separate to the HTML – not inline, same as CSS. Various reasons, including for accessibility and development.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it as another part of the array:

```
$login = array(
    'name'  => 'login',
    'id'    => 'login',
    'value' => set_value('login', 'Email'),
    'onfocus' => "this.value=''",
);
```

However see @ShankarSangoli post, that’s a better way to manage the situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like your form to contain some additional data, like Javascript, you can pass it as a string in the third parameter:

```
 $js = 'onClick="some_function()"';

 echo form_input('username', 'johndoe', $js);
```

It is all documented over at [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Hope this helps!